# Sending hourly messages on whatsapp using python without scanning QR code

Tags: python, api, automation, whatsapp

I need to send hourly messages on a whatsapp group. I have tried Selenium library on python but the issue is I have to manually scan QR code using my mobile phone every time I run my python code. Is there a way to set send whatsapp messages hourly without scanning QR code everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Use twilio bro but we have to pay for service of direct access to whatsapp API.

Comment: Welcome on the SoftwareRecs SE! I suggest to give more info about the software, links, etc.